# Residue field extension is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In ch. I, §9, p. 56 of *Algebraic Number Theory*, Neukirch gives a proof of the statement (Proposition 9.4) that for a normal extension $L/K$ of algebraic number fields, any prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ and any prime $\mathfrak{P} \subset \mathcal{O}_L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$, the corresponding residue field extension $(\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})$ is normal.

The idea of the proof is the following: You let $\theta \in \mathcal{O}_L$ be a representative of an element $\overline{\theta} \in \mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P}$, and let $f(x) \in K[x]$, $\overline{g}(X) \in (\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})[X]$ be the minimal polynomials of $\theta$ and $\overline{\theta}$ respectively over $K$ and $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ respectively.

Then comes the first step that puzzles me: He says that $\overline{\theta} = \theta\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{P})$ is a root of the polynomial $\overline{f}(x) = f(x)\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{p})$, and thence concludes that $\overline{g}(x)$ divides $\overline{f}(x)$ (presumably in $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})[X]$?).

My question is: What does this mean? If we want to show that $\overline{g}(x)$ divides $\overline{f}(x)$, then $\overline{f}(x)$ should be living in $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})[X]$, and hence be a function $\overline{f}: \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p} \to \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$, right? So the expression should be given more explicitly as:
$$\overline{f}(x\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{p})) = f(x)\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{p}).$$
But this $\overline{f}$ is evidently only well-defined if $f$ fixes $\mathfrak{p}$, which is not necessarily the case.

How is this to be understood?

All input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should not be thinking of elements of $R[X]$ as functions $R\to R$. Rather they are formal expressions in the elements of $R$ and the formal element $X$.

Comment: Of course, for each $x\in R$, there is a natural evaluation function $R[X]\to R$ that sends the formal element $X$ to the actual element $x\in R$. In this way we obtain a natural identification of $R[X]$ with certain functions from $R\to R$. But there are many situations (including this one!) where we do not want to make this identification. For example, it makes perfect sense to reduce an element of $\mathcal O_K[X]$ mod $\mathfrak p$: you just do it coefficient-wise. But, as you say, you cannot simply reduce a function $\mathcal O_K\to\mathcal O_K$ modulo $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: A separate point. You can show independently that any finite extension of a finite field is normal.

Comment: @Mathmo123 So any finite extension of a finite field is Galois? I somehow managed to sit through an entire year of Galois theory without knowing that.

Comment: @HenrichWagner - it's not too hard when you think about it. If $L$ is an extension of a finite field $\mathbb F$ and $\hat{L}$ is its Galois closure, then $\mathrm{Gal}(\hat L/\mathbb F)$ is cyclic.... so any subfield is Galois! The point about how to think about $R[X]$ is more fundamental though!